# Looping over Rows of a Dataframe in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

### Rowwise Loops

I have the following dataset concerning student marks.

```
name <- c("John", "Rachel", "Judy", "James", "Oloo")

english <- c("70", "50e", "19c", "38^", "33^")

math <- c("65", "25c", "68", "32^", "50")

science <- c("45", "50", "25c", "27e", "72")
             
social <- c("56", "76", "42", "23^", "68")    

marks <- data.frame(name, english, math, science, social)

marks
```

For a student to pass an exam, they must sit both the continuous assessment and final examination and score at least 40% in each subject.

`Pass`: Where a student has **NO** `e` or `^` after the marks meaning all scores are 40 and over.

`Supplementary`: Where a student has a `^` or an `e`. The `^` means score less than 40. Students with `e` may have more than 40 marks but have failed still for failing to take continuous assessment.

`special`: Student has a `c` but NO `e` or `^`.

`Supplementary and special`: Combination of supplementary and special. This means that a student has `e`, `^` or both and at the same time has a `c`.

`Discontinued`: A student has 4 or more `e`, 4 or more `^`. Also a student could have a combination of `e` and `^` that happens 4 or more times.
**Task**: For each student (that is, a row of data), I want a code in `R` that will return a new column, `comment` as follows.

```
name <- c("John", "Rachel", "Judy", "James", "Oloo")

english <- c("70", "50e", "19c", "38^", "33^")

math <- c("65", "25c", "68", "32^", "50")

science <- c("45", "50", "25c", "27^", "72")
             
social <- c("56", "76", "42", "23^", "68")  

comment <- c("Pass", "Supplementary & Special", "Special", "Discontinued", "Supplementary")

marks_1 <- data.frame(name, english, math, science, social, comment)

marks_1
```

Note again:
`Pass`: Where a student has **NO** `e` or `^` after the marks meaning all scores are 40 and over.

`Supplementary`: Where a student has a `^` or an `e`. The `^` means score less than 40. Students with `e` may have more than 40 marks but have failed still for failing to take continuous assessment.

`special`: Student has a `c` but NO `e` or `^`.

`Supplementary and special`: Combination of supplementary and special. This means that a student has `e`, `^` or both and at the same time has a `c`.

`Discontinued`: A student has 4 or more `e`, 4 or more `^`. Also a student could have a combination of `e` and `^` that happens 4 or more times.

Comment: When does student get "Special" value ? When is it "Discontinued" ? How is row 5 `Supplementary` but row 2 `Supplementary & Special` ?

Comment: Ronak, Thanks. Special - where there is a `c`. Supplementary- when there is a `^` or `e`. Discontinued: Where in  4 or more subjects, a student gets less than 40 or an including 4 `e` or 4 `^`. Pass where the student has no `c`, `e`, and `^`, meaning all subjects are over 40 marks and over. Row 5 is supplementary because the student has a 33^. Row 2 is supplementary and special because the student has `e` and `c` after the marks. Maybe I am not explaining it well.

Comment: `Pass`: Where a student has **NO** `e` or `^`, all scores are 40 and over.
`Supplementary`: Where a student has a `^` or an `e`. The `^` means score less than 40. Students with `e` may have more than 40 marks but have failed still for failing to take continuous assessment.  `special`: Student has a `c` but NO `e` or `^`.
`Supplementary and special`: Combination of supplementary and special. This means that a student has `e`, `^` or both and at the same time has a `c`. `Discontinued`: A student has 4 or more `e`, 4 or more `^` OR a combination of `e` and `^` that happens 4 or more times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to write down each rule manually and apply them for each row.

```
library(dplyr)

apply_rules <- function(x) {
  e_rule <- any(grepl('e', x, fixed = TRUE))
  c_rule <- any(grepl('c', x, fixed = TRUE))
  fail_rule <- any(grepl('^', x, fixed = TRUE))
  case_when(all(grepl('[\\^e]', x)) ~ 'Discontinued',
            (e_rule || fail_rule) && c_rule ~ 'Supplementary & Special', 
            fail_rule || e_rule ~ 'Supplementary',
            c_rule && (c_rule || fail_rule) ~ 'Special', 
            !(e_rule ||  c_rule) ~ 'Pass', 
            fail_rule ~ 'Discontinued' 
            )
}

marks %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(comment = apply_rules(c_across(english:social)))

#  name   english math  science social comment                
#  <chr>  <chr>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>  <chr>                  
#1 John   70      65    45      56     Pass                   
#2 Rachel 50e     25c   50      76     Supplementary & Special
#3 Judy   19c     68    25c     42     Special                
#4 James  38^     32^   27^     23^    Discontinued           
#5 Oloo   33^     50    72      68     Supplementary
```